# QGIS Plugin : Raster Terrain Analysis

Tags: qgis

i recently updated QGIS to 2.14 (Essen).
Unfortunately, the very useful plugin << Raster terrain Analysis >> seems to disappear after the update. It was easily accessible by menu Raster, and now is no more. I tried to reinstall it by the plugin manager - it's not even in the list anymore.
The script seems to be correctly in the plugin folder  ( /Applications/QGIS.app/Contents/PlugIns/qgis )

It is deprecated ? How can I reinstall it ? 
(i'm on Mac and tried to reinstall QGIS and GDAL framework - nothing).

Comment: Plugin appearing in QGIS 2.14.5. fine (Linux Mint 18). Until you solve your issue you can use other functions which gives similar results: _Raster --> Analysis --> DEM (Terrain Models)..._ or individual functions from processing toolbox (SAGA, GDAL, GRASS)

Comment: Thanks PolyGeo. It should be my computer, plugin is still not appearing. I'll try to reinstall again